# How to register successfully for push notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification, swift3

Since I updated my Xcode to Xcode 8:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken:  Data) {
    //
}
```

Is never called, I tried everything:

- Enabled push notifications entitlements in capabilities.
- Imported UserNotifications and added `UIApplicationDelegate`,`UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` .
- Added this to `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

  ```
  if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: {(granted, error) in
          if (granted)
          {

              UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()


          }
          else{
              //Do stuff if unsuccessful...
          }
      })
  ```

Still `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` function is never called! 
Any help please.

Also note I am receiving this warning:

> Instance method
>   `application(:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceTok‌​en:)`
>   nearly matches optional requirement
>   `application(:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceTok‌​en:)` of
>   protocol `UIApplicationDelegate` –

Comment: Have you tried to comment out the entire `didRegisterForRemote...` method and retype it to use code completion?

Comment: yes i did also didnot work

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where Xcode kept marking the code and saying: "nearly matches optional requirement" 
There have been reports that this is a bug and that radar bug reports have been filed for it. I ran into the same issue with

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
```

where it gave me the same warning and the app kept crashing saying that "Delegate must respond to locationManager:didFailWithError:"

A solution that worked for me:

```
 @objc(locationManager:didFailWithError:)
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
       print(error)
}
```

Comment: Hopefully this will be helpful to someone.. I edited my previous response and added the solution that worked for me. Note that you have to use NSError (not Error, since you're using objc code format)